# C#/regex, simple question

Tags: c#, regex

How comes this writes False?

```
Console.Write(Regex.IsMatch("[abcde]{1,16}", "babe"));
```

What's wrong with my regex? Doesn't that regex roughly translate to: contains between 1 and 16 characters, a through e?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your arguments are switched. I.e., use:

```
Regex.IsMatch("babe", "[abcde]{1,16}")
```

instead,

Answer (score 1):

That's going to match any of the characters in "babe" that fall between a and e. So for example, "babez" would match as "babe". I get the sense you want treat it as a string match. Try:

```
[a-e]{1,16}$
```